# How to change the file name by copying the file during an infinite loop

Tags: bash

So I have an loop that will copy a file called file1 during the loop how would it be possible to make a copy of the file called file2, file3 ect... forever?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please provide more details about the context, and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: You realise this will fill up the disk or the inodes list and crash? Yes, you probably want a counter variable and e.g. `while true; do ... ; done` to loop forever, and construct the filename from your counter variable

Comment: Maybe add a few dozen emergency checks, like "is my incrementer above $maxVal?" and "how much space is left on this device now?" Also, maybe throw in a fork bomb each iteration, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hypothetically (I don't recommend it(I really don't recommend it(use at your own risk))):

```
#!/bin/bash

# define 'i' as the variable to contain a number
i=0
# open while loop to cycle condition true (infinitely until you quit the application)
while true; do
# Iterate i = i + 1  (which works because you've defined it as a number previously)
((i++))
# The copy operation which will copy file to file1, file2 file3 ...
cp file file$i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you have X files named myfile1, myfile2, ..., myfileX. So not an infinite loop :) So maybe something like:

```
for f in $(ls myfile*) 
do
  cp $f $f.copy
done
```